# My function works for all elements, instead of each separately

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to make a function which will work for each element separately, however, it either worked for the first element only, or for all elements like right now. I started learning recently, please share your wisdom with me guys) How do I make a function do what I need?

```js
  function toggleClassOnClickAll(clickingObjIds, addToElems, classAdd){

let clickOn = document.querySelectorAll(clickingObjIds);
let addTo = document.querySelectorAll(addToElems);
let delFrom = document.querySelectorAll(addToElems);

let status = 1;
Array.from(clickOn).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function() { 
 if(status == 1){
  Array.from(addTo).forEach(el => el.classList.add(classAdd));
  status = 0; 
 } else if (status == 0){
   
  Array.from(delFrom).forEach(el => el.classList.remove(classAdd));
  status = 1;

 };
}));
 };

 toggleClassOnClickAll(".display-button", ".hidden-el", "block");
```

```css
.element {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hidden-el {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  
}
.display-button{
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}
.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <p class="display-button"> Dispay hidden element </p>
  <div class="hidden-el" id="hidden-id"></div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <p class="display-button"> Dispay hidden element </p>
  <div class="hidden-el" id="hidden-id"></div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <p class="display-button"> Dispay hidden element </p>
  <div class="hidden-el" id="hidden-id"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hint: Take an `event` argument in your handler and use that `event.target`.

Comment: make your elements quique by id and then show it accordingly.

Comment: @tadman Thank you! Please see my code, you meant like this, or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib I would like it to be so simple, but If I will have hundreds of these elements, it will take a lot of unnecessary coding.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```js
function toggleClassOnClickAll(clickingObjIds, addToElems, classAdd) {

  let clickOn = document.querySelectorAll(clickingObjIds);

  let status = 1;
  Array.from(clickOn).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var clickedElement = e.currentTarget.parentElement;
    let hiddenElement = clickedElement.querySelector(addToElems);

    hiddenElement.classList.toggle(classAdd);

  }));
};
toggleClassOnClickAll(".display-button", ".hidden-el", "block");
```

```css
.element {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.hidden-el {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.display-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <p class="display-button"> Dispay hidden element </p>
  <div class="hidden-el" id="hidden-id"></div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <p class="display-button"> Dispay hidden element </p>
  <div class="hidden-el" id="hidden-id"></div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <p class="display-button"> Dispay hidden element </p>
  <div class="hidden-el" id="hidden-id"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `e.currentTarget` is the key here. Nice.